# Unable to create ConnectionString variable to connect to Azure Event Hub: Error: JavaPackage' object is not callable

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to generate dummy to our Event Hub using Python Library **dbldatagen** using the following Python code in databricks

```
import dbldatagen as dg
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType, FloatType
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, DecimalType, StringType, TimestampType, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
num_rows = 10 * 1000000  # number of rows to generate
num_partitions = 8  # number of Spark dataframe partitions


delay_reasons = ["Air Carrier", "Extreme Weather", "National Aviation System", "Security", "Late Aircraft"]

# will have implied column `id` for ordinal of row
flightdata_defn = (dg.DataGenerator(spark, name="flight_delay_data", rows=num_rows, partitions=num_partitions)
                 #.withColumn("body",StringType(), False)
                 .withColumn("flightNumber", "int", minValue=1000, uniqueValues=10000, random=True)
                 .withColumn("airline", "string", minValue=1, maxValue=500,  prefix="airline", random=True, distribution="normal")
                 .withColumn("original_departure", "timestamp", begin="2020-01-01 01:00:00", end="2020-12-31 23:59:00", interval="1 minute", random=True)
                 .withColumn("delay_minutes", "int", minValue=20, maxValue=600, distribution=dg.distributions.Gamma(1.0, 2.0))
                 .withColumn("delayed_departure",  "timestamp", expr="cast(original_departure as bigint) +  (delay_minutes * 60) ", baseColumn=["original_departure", "delay_minutes"])
                 .withColumn("reason", "string", values=delay_reasons, random=True)
                )

df_flight_data = flightdata_defn.build(withStreaming=True, options={'rowsPerSecond': 10})


streamingDelays = (
  df_flight_data
    .groupBy(
      #df_flight_data.body,
      df_flight_data.flightNumber,
      df_flight_data.airline,
      df_flight_data.original_departure,
      df_flight_data.delay_minutes,
      df_flight_data.delayed_departure,
      df_flight_data.reason,
      window(df_flight_data.original_departure, "1 hour")
    )
    .count()
)

writeConnectionString = sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
checkpointLocation = "///checkpoint"

# ehWriteConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
# ehWriteConf = {
#   'eventhubs.connectionString' : writeConnectionString
# }

ehWriteConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString' : writeConnectionString
}
```

However, the following line of code gives me the error

```
writeConnectionString = sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
```

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the following package from Maven in Databricks:

**`com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.22`**

[image]

[image]

```py
streamingDelays.withColumn('body', F.to_json(
       F.struct(*streamingDelays.columns),
       options={"ignoreNullFields": False}))\
    .select('body')\
    .writeStream \
    .format("eventhubs") \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .options(**ehWriteConf) \
    .option("checkpointLocation",checkpointLocation) \
    .start()
```

Output in Stream Analytics job.

[image]

Refer this [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/README.md#latest-releases) for installing azure eventhub connector according to your spark version

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS, thanks for reaching out. What was the code you executed to get the Output in Stream Analytics job?

Comment: Actually it is not code. You need to connect azure event hub in azure stram analytics job. Taking azure event hub as source.